# Prevent if statement based on value using array

Tags: javascript

So the code below checks whether a value has 'CA' before it proceeds as shown below:

```
if (this.value !== 'CA') {
    formStatePick.style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#stateWarning b#stateName').textContent = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
} else {
    formStatePick.style.display = 'none';
}
```

I want to be able to toss in an array called states and then use the array values to check if it does not equal.

Here is my attempt but it doesn't work:

```
var States = [
    "CA",
    "IL",
];

if (this.value !== States) {
    formStatePick.style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#stateWarning b#stateName').textContent = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
} else {
    formStatePick.style.display = 'none';
}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```js
const states = [
  "CA",
  "IL"
];

const value = 'CA';


if (!states.includes(value)) {
  console.log('does not contain');
} else {
  console.log('does contain');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative, You can also use `indexOf`

```js
const states = [
  "CA",
  "IL"
];

const value = 'CA';


if (states.indexOf(value) < 0) 
  console.log('does not contain');
else 
  console.log('does contain');
```